# Any way to spoof original webrtc ip address?

Tags: security, browser, ip, webrtc

Is there any way to spoof original WebRTC ip address on regular browsers like chrome, firefox and opera?

For example: I using some proxy and would like to spoof my WebRTC ip address same like proxy ip address. I don't need to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Running a TURN server is the best way. A TURN server acts as a proxy, you can can send and receive all your traffic through a remote host first.

You can then set `iceTransportPolicy` to `relay` in your `RTCConfiguration`. The PeerConnection will then only connect through that TURN server.