# Force Chromium to Use Proxy IP Address in WebRTC instead of Public IP

Tags: proxy, webrtc, stun, turn

Browsers leaks Public IP through WebRTC protocols while routing traffics through browser specific proxies such as chrome vpn extensions. but using Native VPN Application (OS Specific) doesn't produce public ip through WebRTC.

How to overcome this problem and force chromium to use proxy IP instead of public IP for WebRTC communication.

Note- Blocking WebRTC from Browser does hide the public ip but many websites eg. google.com, godaddy.com treats you as a bot and blacklist you from using some of their services.

This issue is more related to browser fingerprinting than ungoogling stuffs..

No Extensions available to solve this problem till now but some of the automation tools such as Kameleo.com is able to do such things but those are pricy.

Possible solutions
Force chromium to use proxy ip through ICE Framework TURN/STUN signaling services

I also don't know how to seup STUN connection so please also guide me for the coding part.

[https://isaacbrains.com](https://isaacbrains.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: Configure and deploy your own TURN server and configure your WebRTC app to use relay candidates only via [iceTransportPolicy](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcicetransportpolicy) and use only TURN for your [iceServers](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtciceserver).

Something like this:

```
let config = {
                 iceServers: [{urls: "turn:turn.yourdomain.com:3478"}],
                 iceTransportPolicy:"relay"
             };
```

WebRTC does not use browser proxies. Browser proxies bridge connections via http/https to websites. And browser proxies don't fit into the model WebRTC uses to connect to another client ad-hoc packet transfer of UDP packets.

STUN exists primarily for clients to discover and share their own public IP address and port mapping. It sounds like you want to avoid STUN since you don't want srflx candidates anyway.

TURN is a relay server protocol for WebRTC, VOIP, and other types of P2P connections. It's primary job is to be a fallback when direct client to client communication is not possible. But it sounds like you want to avoid that altogether and just have the SDP advertise your relay (TURN) addresses only.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4nfxQcdq7I See this video. I just want to spoof the public and private ip address while using external proxy (e.g. VPN) for websites only.

Comment: **What are you really trying to do?**

Comment: just to spoof webrtc public ip leaks while using proxy instead of blocking webrtc

Comment: If you don't want to outright block webrtc, hide your public IP address, and still have your Zoom calls work, you really need to have your entire network on NAT. Exactly what VPN does.

Comment: When STUN request to discover our public ip we just want to put our proxy ip on that. We dont need zoom call or any other video/audio functionality. I hope you have understood that youtube video on How that person is spoofing their public ip while using proxy. check similar question here .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71002314/any-way-to-spoof-original-webrtc-ip-address

Comment: I strongly suspect the products you reference that hide your IP from webrtc are installing themselves as a browser plugin and shimming the webrtc API itself. And I suspect it either intercepts the ICE candidate messages, modifies the SDP in place, and/or reconfigures the ICE server configuration to not use STUN or TURN servers.

Comment: The approach I would consider taking is a browser plugin that intercepts the `RTCPeerConfiguration` call and modifies the list of iceServers before being passed to it.  You can effectively pass it your own STUN and TURN servers. And your proxy can implement either implement TURN or STUN and act as a NAT.